# Reflections in polyhedral groups (tetrahedral group)

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Consider the symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron (pyramid). I am trying to work out the group of reflections.

My observations so far: There are only three reflections. These are the reflections corresponding each to the plan going through one edge of the tetrahedron and the face opposite.

> Question 1: How do I prove that these are all reflections of the tetrahedron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick abstract approach to this, which shows that there are $6$ more reflections, is to notice that the symmetry group of the regular tetrahedron is $S_4$, since any permutation of the vertices forms a unique symmetry of the tetrahedron. We want to know which permutations have an odd sign, since the ones with an even sign correspond to rotations. However there should be $12$ such reflections, not $6$. In particular, you need to account for the reflection corresponding to the permutation $(1\,2\,3\,4)$ and other $4$-cycles, which have odd sign and are hence reflections. I don't know of an easy way to characterize these reflections, except by noting that $(1\,2\,3\,4)=(1\,2)(2\,3)(3\,4)$ and composing the relevant reflections.

Comment: This is neat. I want to use it for all regular polyhedral groups... but why is it clear that each permutation group of vertices is isomorphic to the symmetric group for some $n$?

Comment: @user The fact that a regular simplex (e.g. triangle, tetrahedron) in $n$-dimensions has symmetry group $S_{n+1}$ follows from the fact that all the edges from a single vertex are linearly independent - meaning you can map any vertices to any others - and that any linear map is a symmetry (which follows from the shape being regular). In general, you can note that the map, for symmetry $x$
$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}1&&\text{if $x$ is a rotation}\\-1&&\text{if $x$ is a reflection}\end{cases}$$
forms a homomorphism to $(\{1,-1\},\cdot)$, meaning either half or none of the symmetries are reflections.